# Using Google Scripts with sheet to send an email on cell change

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

This is the code i currently have. I did some myself but pulled most from other's code I have found. However I cannot get the code to run properly. I keep getting several different errors and the code keeps failing. The error I am getting are TypeError: Cannot read propery 'range' of undefined at checkStatusIsApproved(code:9:17) at sendEmailOnApproval(Code:28:22) at onEdit(Code:3:5)

```
function onEdit(e){

    sendEmailOnApproval(e);
}

function checkStatusIsApproved(e){

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Client_Status');
  var range = e.range;


  if(range.getColumn() <= 4 && 
     range.getLastColumn() >= 4)
  {
    var edited_row = range.getRow();
    var status = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet.getRange(edited_row,5).getValue();
    
    if(status == 'Canceled')
    {
      return edited_row;
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
function sendEmailOnApproval(e)
{
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var approved_row = checkStatusIsApproved();
  
  if(approved_row <= 0)
  {
    return;
  }
  
  sendEmailByRow(approved_row);
}
function sendEmailByRow(row)
{
  var emailClient = row_values[0];
  var values = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getSheetByName('Client_Status').getRange(row,1,row,5).getValues();
  var row_values = values[0];
  var mail = composeApprovedEmail(row_values);
  
  MailApp.sendEmail(emailClient.email,emailClient.subject,emailClient.message);
}

function composeApprovedEmail(row_values)
{
  var emailClient = row_values[0];
  var messageClient = row_values[1];
  var headline = row_values[3];
  
  var message = messageClient;
  var subject = headline;
  return({message:message,subject:subject, email:emailClient});
}
```

Comment: It seems that your script is run by the trigger. About `Cannot read propery 'range' of undefined at checkStatusIsApproved(code:9:17)`, in this case, for example, when you directly run the script, I think that such error occurs because the event object `e` is not declared. So how about editing cell? But, when your `onEdit` is used as the simple trigger, an error occurs. Because the simple trigger cannot use `MailApp.sendEmail`. So it is required to use the installable trigger. But I'm not sure about your actual goal from your question. So I apologize for this unclear comment.

Comment: When I change a client from active to cancelled I want to send an email for off boarding. When I change the cell to cancelled those are the errors I am getting under the executions tab.

Comment: Thank you for replying.I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand `When I change a client from active to cancelled I want to send an email for off boarding. When I change the cell to cancelled those are the errors I am getting under the executions tab.`. Can I ask you about the detail of it?

Comment: yea, absolutely. When I change the contents of any cell in column E to the word 'canceled' I would like an email to be sent out.

Comment: Thank you for replying. When you when your `onEdit` is used as the simple trigger, an error occurs. Because the simple trigger cannot use `MailApp.sendEmail`. So it is required to use the installable trigger. How about this?

Comment: I have the trigger with these options selected: 
Choose which function to run-onEdit  
Select event source: From spreadsheet
Select event type: On edit

Comment: Thank you for replying. In your situation, you installed the function of `onEdit` as the installable trigger. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: yes that is correct

Comment: Thank you for replying. In that case, your `onEdit` is run 2 times as the simple trigger and the installable trigger. I think that your error might occur as the simple trigger. So, how about renaming the function name and reinstall it? By the way, when I saw your script, `mail` of `var mail = composeApprovedEmail(row_values);` is not used. How about this?

Comment: For example, when `var mail = composeApprovedEmail(row_values);` is modified to `var emailClient = composeApprovedEmail(row_values);`, is that the result you expect?

Comment: nope. still getting the same errors when i changed that

Comment: Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. About `nope. still getting the same errors when i changed that`, when you change above suggestions, the same error of `TypeError: Cannot read propery 'range' of undefined at checkStatusIsApproved(code:9:17)` occurs. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: What sheet are you starting the function from and what are you editing to get the trigger?

Comment: the sheet is called Client_Status